# Trying to apply multiple independent filters on LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to create a LINQ query that returns either all results, or a filtered result or list of results based on multiple input boxes. However, I currently cannot seem to get a value to come from the 2nd input box, where I am trying to input a social security number and use it as a filtering parameter. Every time I try to run the filter, I am being shown that the ssnString is null.

Controller "Get" Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string ssnString)
{
    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    ViewData["nameFilter"] = searchString;
    ViewData["ssnFilter"] = ssnString;

    var members = from m in _context.Member
                  select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        members = members.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ssnString))
    {
        members = members.Where(s => s.SSN.Equals(ssnString));
    }
```

Index View:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Filter by last name: <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["nameFilter"]" /> |
            @*<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" /> |*@
            Find by SSN: <input type="number" name="SSNSearchString" value="@ViewData["ssnFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back To Full Index</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like for all results to be returned if neither input box is given a value, and if either the name or ssn Filter box is given a value, then it is used as the filtration string. As mentioned, I currently do not see a value for the ssnFilter being passed to the controller and to the query, but the nameFilter seems to work perfectly fine.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: The problem here doesn't have anything to do with LINQ, it's about how to properly submit values from your MVC page to your backend Action methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for model binding to work here you need to make sure that the name of the HTML control matches up to the input parameter in your action method.

Your input box is called `SSNSearchString`:

`<input type="number" name="SSNSearchString" value="@ViewData["ssnFilter"]" />`

But in your action method you declare a parameter as `ssnString`:

`Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string ssnString)`

If you change it to:

`Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string ssnSearchString)`

Then the model binder should be able to match it up.

Comment: I believe that the value of the data in the view (value="ViewData["ssnFilter"]) is what I am passing to the controller (ViewData["ssnFilter"] = ssnString;). Am I wrong in that belief?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't be using `ViewData` to send data back to the controller.  This is standard HTML form processing, so when you click your Submit button, it will send form encoded values to the backend.  Form encoded values are basically just key-value pairs where the key is the name of the HTML element, and the value is the value of the element.

Comment: Right on. The information from your initial reply did solve my issue. Thank you very much for your help.